# Java JDBC blocking connectors

Tags: java, jdbc, io

Java JDBC connectors block I/O.

While it is being blocked, will the thread consume CPU time? like is the thread busy-waiting / polling the server's response?

Does this mean all the blocking JDBC drivers based Java servers are doomed?

e.g. if database server has latency in response, a lot of CPU cycles will be wasted in the blocked thread?

I know there are NIO in Java which was introduced since 1.7 but not very much libs are based on them neither is JDBC itself compatible with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a thread is waiting for a blocking io operation to complete it is in a waiting state that doesn't consume CPU resources.